# Server side rendering and media queries

Tags: reactjs, media-queries, server-side-rendering

I have an app that renders different components based on screen size. It uses media queries.

I am also using server side rendering. On server side there are no media queries so it ends up rendering everything server side which can cause mismatch with client. How do I detect screen size while SSR and render only the required components?